# In distributed tensorflow, FIFOQueue.enqueue() sometimes doesn't work

Tags: tensorflow, distributed

I used following lines to create a shared queue across different workers.

```
   with tf.device("/job:ps/task:0"):
        with tf.variable_scope("global"):
            self.queue = tf.FIFOQueue(20, None)
```

In ps worker:

```
self.queue.dequeue()
```

In other workers,

```
self.queue.enqueue(somethings)
```

However, I found sometimes the enqueue operation doesn't work that nothing is enqueued, and there is no error or expectation. Does anyone have idea?

Comment: Can you provide more details as to what's going on? It's hard to help with such limited information. Thanks!

Comment: i solved this problem by adding shared_name = 'shared_name' in FIFOQueue...so it can be shared by other workers